# refactoring code from syncronous to asyncronous flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, promise

### What I have

**I have to take code that was build for web with react and adapt it to react native.** One of the biggest problems is, web storage(localStorage) works synchronously, while react-native storage implementations works asynchronously [AsyncStorage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/). So all code that run/use web storage must now be wrapped inside an `async/await` or use `promises` in react-native implementation.

#### Code before refactoring - with synchronous storage

```js
// get items from localstorage - synchronous wrapper implementation
export const getTokens = () => ({
  auth:
    localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY.AUTH) ||
    sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY.AUTH),
  refresh:
    localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY.REFRESH) ||
    sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY.REFRESH)
});

const refreshPromise = useRef<Promise<boolean>>();

const refreshToken = (): Promise<boolean> => {
    if (!!refreshPromise.current) {
      return refreshPromise.current;
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // getting items from storage synchronous
      const token = getTokens().refresh;

      // nested promise x_x
      return tokenRefresh({ variables: { token } }).then(refreshData => {
        if (!!refreshData.data.tokenRefresh?.token) {
          // this is other method that use localstorage inside promises, more problems x_x
          setAuthToken(refreshData.data.tokenRefresh.token, persistToken);
          return resolve(true);
        }

        return resolve(false);
      });
    });
  };
```

### Problem

The problem is that I have encountered situations where storage is used inside a promise, and to adapt it to react-native I have to use asyncronous flow. i.e use `async/await` inside of a `new Promise() constructor` that is an anti-pattern.

the above brings a lot of problems, although using `async/await` inside the promise constructor is valid, firstly it makes the code less readable and secondly more difficult to debbug and check for errors. Another problem is *synchronous* implementation also nests promises which makes the code more complex to refactor.

#### Current code - with asynchronous storage

```js
// get items from localstorage - asynchronous wrapper implementation
export const getTokens = async () => {
  const auth = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(TokenStorageKey.AUTH);
  const refresh = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(TokenStorageKey.REFRESH);

  return auth && refresh
    ? {
        auth,
        refresh,
      }
    : null;
};

const refreshPromise = useRef<Promise<boolean>>();

const refreshToken = (): Promise<boolean> => {
    if (refreshPromise.current) {
      return refreshPromise.current;
    }

    return new Promise(async resolve => {
      // getting items from storage asynchronous
      const tokens = await getTokens();
      const refresh = tokens?.refresh;

      // nested promise x_x
      return tokenRefresh({variables: {refresh}}).then(async refreshData => {
        if (refreshData.data?.tokenRefresh?.token) {
          // this is other method that use localstorage inside promises, more problems x_x
          await setAuthToken(refreshData.data.tokenRefresh.token);

          return resolve(true);
        }

        return resolve(false);
      });
    });
  };
```

### What I want

according to this [eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-async-promise-executor):

> If a Promise executor function is using await, this is usually a sign that it is not actually necessary to use the new Promise constructor, or the scope of the new Promise constructor can be reduced.*

I'm not clear how to achieve what the eslint rule mentions or make this code more escalable and easier to debug, Removing promises and avoiding nesting of asynchronous processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you don't need the `new Promise(...)` wrapper since you already have promise-driven operations.  You were just wrapping existing promises in a new manually created promise which is not necessary (and considered an anti-pattern).  You can change to this:

```
const refreshToken = async (): Promise < boolean > => {
    if (refreshPromise.current) {
        return refreshPromise.current;
    }

    // getting items from storage asynchronous
    const tokens = await getTokens();
    const refresh = tokens?.refresh;

    const refreshData = await tokenRefresh({ variables: { refresh } });
    if (refreshData.data?.tokenRefresh?.token) {
        // this is other method that use localstorage inside promises, more problems x_x
        await setAuthToken(refreshData.data.tokenRefresh.token);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Note, I also removed the mixture of `await` and `.then()` since you usually don't want to mix those two programming styles.

FYI, I don't know your typed-syntax here so please forgive any slight syntax mistakes in that regard.  This should still show you the general way this can be done without wrapping it in a `new Promise(...)`.